# How to remove login pop up in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to login to Flipkart and make a purchase. But as soon as i click on the Login/SignUp button, a pop up comes suggesting existing usernames and has a Cancel button.

I am unable to find code for Cancel button through Inspect. How can i handle this?

Comment: You'll have to post the relevant HTML. I see a Login dialog that has a "Enter Email/Mobile number", "Enter Password", Login, Request OTP, etc. and it has a cancel X on the top right of the popup. If you Inspect that, you will see `<button class="_2AkmmA _29YdH8">✕</button>`. Is that what you are talking about? It's hard to tell with the little info you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

To interact with the new window you have to change the element with which Selenium interacts, you can use the switchTo method and then indicate the name of the window:

```
driver.switchTo().window("windowName");
```

If you do not know the name of that popup that appears to you, you can get all the windows and look for the cancellation button:

```
for (String window : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
  driver.switchTo().window(window);
  List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.id("cancel"))
  if (!elements.isEmpty()) {
    elements.get(0).click();
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I found that this is an issue with Chrome Driver. With FireFox, i am not getting this pop up

Comment: It's a popup, not a new browser window.

Comment: @JeffC It works in the same way. SwitchTo has options to even move through the alert boxes

Comment: This is an HTML dialog/popup, not a new browser window. It doesn't work this way.